# Installing PHP Recess framework, getting error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bitnami, recess

Trying to install the [Recess API Framework](http://www.recessframework.org/page/installation)
on an EC2 instance using the Bitnami AMI. I get the error

```
Error connecting to data source: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tried this [solution](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/) but it turns out the `[client]` section in `my.cnf` already has the socket pointing to the location of `mysql.sock`, verified by using `sudo find / -name mysql.sock`

MySQL works just fine for me in all ways I've found, so I'm curious if it's something I need to configure in Recess.

Answer (score 0):

In a BitNami AMI the MySQL socket is /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.

This the official BitNami documentation: http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/MySQL#What_is_the_default_configuration.3f. In the AMI the installation directory (installdir in the documentation) is /opt/bitnami